# How to circumvent Django's req/resp cycle when updating it's internal state

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, redis

I have a Django application that uses large data structures in-memory (due to performance constraints). This wouldn't be a problem, but I'm using Heroku, where if the python web process takes more than 30s to start, it will be stopped as it's considered a timeout error. Because of the problem aforementioned, I've used a daemon process(worker in Heroku) to handle the construction of the data structures and Redis to handle the message passing between processes.

When the worker finishes(approx 1 minute), it stores the data structures(50Mb or so) in Redis.

And now comes the crux of the matter...Django follows the request/response paradigm and it's synchronised. This implies a **Django view** should exist to handle the callback from the worker announcing it's done. Even if I use something fancier like a pub/sub from Redis, I'm still forced to evaluate the queue populated by a publisher in a view.

How can I circumvent the necessity of using a Django view? Isn't there an async way of doing this?

Below is the solution where I use a pub/sub inside a view. This seems bad, but I can't think of another way.

***views.py***

```
...
# data_handler can enqueue tasks on the default queue
data_handler = DataHandler()

strict_redis = redis.from_url(settings.DEFAULT_QUEUE)
pub_sub = strict_redis.pubsub()
# this puts the job of constructing the large data structures
# on the default queue so a worker can pick it up. Being async, 
# it returns with an empty set of data structures.
data_structures = data_handler.start() 
pub_sub.subscribe(settings.FINISHED_DATA_STRUCTURES_CHANNEL)

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def store_and_fetch(request):
   user_data = json.load(request.body.decode('utf8'))

   message = pub_sub.get_message()
   if message:
       command = message['data'] if 'data' in message else ''
       if command == settings.FINISHED_DATA_STRUCTURES_INIT.encode('utf-8'):
           # this takes the data from redis and updates data_structures
           data_handler.update(data_structures) 

   return HttpResponse(compute_response(user_data, data_structures))
```

**Update**: After working for multiple months with this, I can now say it's definitely better(and wiser) **NOT** to fiddle with Django's request/response cycle. There are things like Django RQ Scheduler, or Celery that can do async tasks just fine. If you want to update the main web process after some repeatable job completed, it's simpler to use something like python ***requests*** package, sending a POST to the web process from the worker that did the scheduled job. In this way we don't circumvent Django's mechanisms, and more importantly, it's simpler to do overall.

Regarding the Heroku constraints I mentioned at the beginning of the post.  At the moment I wrote this question I was quite a newbie with heroku and didn't know much about the release phase. In the release phase we can set up all the complex logic we need for the main process. Thus, at the end of the release phase, we simply need to notify the web process, in the manner I've described above and use some distributed memory buffer (even Redis will work just fine).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. There's no need to use views if you're not processing requests. For offline work, use Celery.

Comment: The views are strongly coupled with the heavy data structures(heavy in the sense that their computation requires a lot of cpu effort and memory, as 50Mb is pretty large to have in memory for a running web app). Even if I use celery or any other daemon manager, there's still a point when the global data structures variables must be updated thus you need to either tap the Django req/resp cycle, practically in a view to update it's internal state, or do something fancy elsewhere.